# How to copy html div to another div without display none div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure like below. In `lookbook-pointadding` I need to copy only the `div` elements where the `display: block` is set.

My code doesn't remove the `div` with `display: none`.

I also tried `$("#lookbook-pointadding").clone().appendTo("#lookbook-pointedit")` but it is not working also.

Can anyone tell where I'm going wrong?

```html
<div id="lookbook-pointedit"></div>
<div id="lookbook-pointadding">
  <div class="drag" style="display: none">A</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: none">B</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: block">C</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: none">D</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: block">E</div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#lookbook-pointadding.drag').css('display') == 'none') {
    $(this).remove(); //already tried $('#lookbook-pointadding.drag').removed();
  }
  var point = $('div#lookbook-pointadding').html();
  $('#lookbook-pointedit').append(point);
})
```

Comment: To explain why your code doesn't work: First, `$(this)` in `$(this).remove();` is your submit button. Second, `$('#lookbook-pointadding.drag')` returns a jQuery collection of multiple elements, and its CSS property "display" is `undefined`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this you can use the `:visible` selector to retrieve only the child `div` elements which are shown in the DOM. Then you can `clone()` them and append to the required target. Try this:

```js
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $clones = $('#lookbook-pointadding div:visible').clone();
  $('#lookbook-pointedit').append($clones);
})
```

```css
#lookbook-pointedit {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lookbook-pointedit"></div>
<div id="lookbook-pointadding">
  <div class="drag" style="display: none">A</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: none">B</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: block">C</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: none">D</div>
  <div class="drag" style="display: block">E</div>
</div>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```